# Herokuapp latency only on free stack only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I use free Cedar for an app under development. When I open my root `home%html` (no database access yet), there is latency of 3 to 5 seconds or more.

Will this be fixed when I paid? If yes, what should I upgrade to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this because Heroku will idle the application if it doesn't receive traffic within 1hr. You can read more about this at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos. When you pay it simply means your application will not idle so therefore you will not experience this bootup time. After you've hit your application for the first time is it then more responsive?

Comment: After you've hit your application for the first time is it then more responsive? < Yes, it is.